# How to find a sensible approximation of $R\dot{\theta}^2+\ddot{\theta}(R\theta-l)+g\cos\theta=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The differential equation  $$R\dot{\theta}^2+\ddot{\theta}(R\theta-l)+g\cos\theta=0$$ is derived from considering a pendulum attached to the uppermost part of a disk. [image]

As in the picture above (but remember the string is attached to the intersection with the y-axis).

Anyways, I was approximating this by considering small oscillations, as usual. To end up with something like

$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{R\dot{\theta}}{R\theta_0-l}+\frac{g\cos\theta_0}{R\theta_0-l}=0$$

But this has a complex solution, and a real valued log function, which doesn't seem like an oscillation at all or physically sound.

The solution manual to my book approximates the equation as
$$\ddot{\epsilon}+\frac{g\sin\theta_0}{l-R\theta_0}\epsilon=\frac{g\cos\theta_0}{l-R\theta_0}$$
Where $\epsilon=\theta-\theta_0$. The equation doesn't make sense to me, especially the second term on the LHS.

So I was wondering if you guys could help me. Perhaps give me a hint or two... Or perhaps tell me what the author of the solutions manual did?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume $\theta_0$ is the equilibrium position. Isn't it more natural to make $\theta_0$ simply $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by re-orienting the y-axis against gravity?

Comment: Yes, it is the equilibrium position. The y axis is already against gravity, perhaps I don't see what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta = \theta_0 + \epsilon$, plugging into your equation and keeping only terms up to order $\epsilon$ we get
\begin{align}
R \dot \theta^2 + \ddot \theta(R \theta - l) + g \cos \theta & = \ddot \epsilon (R \theta_0 - l) + g \cos (\theta_0 + \epsilon) \\
& = \ddot \epsilon(R \theta_0 - l) + g[\cos \theta_0 - \epsilon \sin \theta_0] = 0.
\end{align}
Rearranging gives the result from the manual.

Comment: Do you know if the original equation has any solution at all? I wish I knew more about the theory of DE to classify such an equation.

Comment: The original equation is highly nonlinear and so in general the solutions are non unique, (existence is also usually difficult as there may be no solution at all for the specified initial conditions). That being said, the constant solution $\theta_0 = \pi/2 + \pi n$ for any $n$ is _a_ solution